# Bowling scheduler

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a scheduler for a bowling tournament. The problem I have is that some of the bowlers share a private bowling ball. So bowlers with the same bowlingball number can't be in the same turn.

I can produce a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {1:None,2:1,3:None,4:None,5:None,6:1,7:2,8:2,9:3,10:None}
```

dict = { bowler_id, shared_ball} (None = no shared ball)

Here is my first attempt which has issues:

```
from operator import itemgetter

bowlers = {1:None,2:1,3:None,4:None,5:None,6:1,7:2,8:2,9:3,10:None,11:None,12:None,13:None,14:None,15:None,16:1,17:None,18:None,19:None,20:None,21:2,22:3,23:None}
Lanes = 6
Rounds = 6
Schedule = {}

sortedlist = sorted(bowlers.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

for x in xrange(1,Lanes+1):
    Schedule[''.join(['Lane', str(x)])] = []

while len(sortedlist) > 0:
    z = zip(Schedule,sortedlist)
    for i in z:
        Schedule[i[0]].append((i[1][0] , i[1][1]))
        sortedlist.pop(0)
print Schedule
```

I have these issues/concerns:

this approach works has the opposite effect: because I iter over a sorted list, the bowlers with the same ball are garanteed in the same turn.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The output of the programm is:

```
   {    
    'Lane6': [(9, 3), (6, 1), (10, None), (17, None)], 
    'Lane5': [(22, 3), (16, 1), (11, None), (18, None)], 
    'Lane4': [(7, 2), (1, None), (12, None), (19, None)], 
    'Lane3': [(8, 2), (3, None), (13, None), (20, None)], 
    'Lane2': [(21, 2), (4, None), (14, None), (23, None)], 
    'Lane1': [(2, 1), (5, None), (15, None)]
}
```

Every column is a turn on all lanes. When you look at the first column you see that shared balls 3 and 2 occure more then once in a column. This wrong because you cannot have two bowlers with the same ball in one turn.

A correct output would be something like:

```
{   
    'Lane6': [(10, None),   (9, 3),     (6, 1),     (17, None)], 
    'Lane5': [(22, 3),      (16, 1),    (11, None), (18, None)], 
    'Lane4': [(7, 2),       (1, None),  (12, None), (19, None)], 
    'Lane3': [(3, None),    (13, None), (8, 2),     (20, None)], 
    'Lane2': [(14, None),   (21, 2),    (4, None),  (23, None)], 
    'Lane1': [(2, 1),       (5, None),  (15, None)]
}
```

The order of bowlers may be randon, as long a there are no shared balls in one turn.

Comment: Actually what you want to have as desire output?

Comment: @Kasra I have added the desired output to the topic.

Comment: *"the order matters... so a dictionary is not good"* - [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: so based on what algorithm you want to generate this output??? what about `Nones` ???please ask your question completely !!! if you want a proper answer !

Comment: @Kasra I have edited the question and the code. It is ok if I get the output for 1 round (for simplicity sake). The code produces the output as show. As you can see are the first entries for Lane6 and Lane5 (9,3) and (22,3). This is wrong because that means bowler 9 and 22 share ball 3 and are in the same turn (turn1).

I hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: do you want all possible round with len `4` ?

Comment: @Kasra None means there is no shared ball, and it is ok there are multiple bowlers with None in one turn.

Comment: how you choose `[(9, 3), (6, 1), (10, None), (17, None)]` for `lane6` ? i mean why those indexes?

Comment: way you dont use another key with `None` value instead 10 or 17 ?

Comment: I thought this would be the best way to store and access the data, and produce a CSV output with this.

Comment: @Kasra The output comes from a database (by Django). When no "shared ball" is chosen, the output is None. Of course I can change None to 0 (or any other value) by setting a default value.

Comment: excuse me i cant understand the algorithm of your question ! how you choose` [(9, 3), (6, 1), (10, None), (17, None)]` for `lane6` ????//

Comment: @Kasra I am just itering over the list of bowlers, and exactly here lays the problem, I haven't figured out an algorithm. I get the feeling I am on the completely wrong track...

Comment: so please add desire out put to your question ! ( if it is long add a part of it)

Comment: @Kasra I have edited/restyled the question, and added the desired code. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for a most interesting challenge!

I've renamed some identifiers to be more meaningful, and I've changed
ball `None` to ball `0` to make the output neater.

This program groups bowlers according to which ball they use, then
chooses at most one from each group, plus any number of bowlers who
don't use a shared ball.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from random import shuffle
from json import dumps     # for pretty printing of results

bowlers2balls = {
    1:0,2:1,3:0,4:0,5:0,6:1,7:2,8:2,9:3,10:0,11:0,12:0,13:0,
    14:0,15:0,16:1,17:0,18:0,19:0,20:0,21:2,22:3,23:0
}

Lanes = 6
Schedule = {}
min_turns = (len(bowlers2balls) - 1) / Lanes + 1

# Create a list of lists. Bowlers with a shared ball are all in the
# same sublist. Each bowler without a shared ball gets their own
# sublist. Ball numbers do not appear here.

shared = [[tup[0] for tup in bowlers2balls.items() if tup[1] == ball]
          for ball in set(bowlers2balls.values()) if ball]
for grp in shared:
    shuffle(grp)
unshared = [[tup[0]] for tup in bowlers2balls.items() if not tup[1]]
full_bgroups = shared + unshared

# Generate random schedules until we get one with minimum turns. It
# often happens that we get a suboptimal one because the bowlers with
# shared balls aren't used up.

while True:
    for lane in xrange(1,Lanes+1):
        Schedule['Lane{}'.format(lane)] = []

    bgroups = deepcopy(full_bgroups)
    while bgroups:
        shuffle(bgroups)
        for i, lane in enumerate(Schedule.keys()):
            if i >= len(bgroups):
                break
            bowler = bgroups[i].pop()
            Schedule[lane].append(
                ('{:2d}'.format(bowler),
                 bowlers2balls[bowler]))
        # Remove emptied lists from bgroups
        bgroups = filter(None, bgroups)

    turns = max([len(s) for s in Schedule.values()])
    if turns <= min_turns:
        break

print (dumps(Schedule, sort_keys=True)
       .strip('{}')
       .replace(']], ', ']],\n'))
```

Comment: @Tom_Zych Thank you for the great answer! When I started with this problem I thought it would be easy, but it was indeed a challenge. The only thing I need to add is a validation that no too many "shared balls" are used, because then it becomes an endless loop.I think I can use the shared list for this.